# App wont push data inside Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on chat app for summerschool. This is my first android app and we were told to use the Firebase. While using in built login in Firebase is pretty simple, i read that you cant access the list of registered users, so i was trying to get past the problem. I made another table. 
After the login of user, i am searching in the table for his email, if it isnt there, his email (used as nickname) is added to the table. Then, i would like to use the content of table, to create chats with other registered users. However, for some reasons, my app is not pushing the User object to the Firebase, as i have checked it in console. It just isnt there. Where is the catch? Code always enters the inner part of the if.

Code for the part, where I am sending it to Firebase.

```
       @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();

            setUserInfo();

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("server/users").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                        new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                System.out.println("Am i inside?" + dataSnapshot.hasChildren());
                                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                                    User user = new User(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("server/users").push().setValue(user);
                                    System.out.println("I am at the end.  " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() + " " + FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("server/users").toString());
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                System.out.println("ERROR: " + databaseError.toString());
                            }
                        }
                );

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

                // Close the app
                finish();
            }
        }
}
```

My user class:

```
public class User {
    private String nickName;
    public User(){}
    public User(String nickName){
    }
    public String getNickName(){
        return nickName;
    }
    public void setNickName(String nickName){
        this.nickName=nickName;
    }
}
```

With this code, i would like to get the users back from the firebase:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("server/users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            User user = userSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            if (user.getNickName() != FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())
                                users.add(user);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide the data hierarchy on Firebase, or if you added users by code you can provide us this part too will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly creating a "Users" node in your database, then storing
all new users to that node. 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").haschild(email);
Check if the User node has this email if not...
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(email).setValue(new user());
And you can listen to the Users node as need.